# How to deal with large spikes in time series feature values

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, feature-engineering

Assume I want to convert time series features into stationary features by taking the percentage difference from the previous time step to the current. This can result in massive spikes where the feature went from 0 to say, 10,000 and then back again.

How can I best deal with these types of features so that they would be handled well by a regression or neural network? I know the obvious thing is to try RNNs but I want to exhaust the vanilla neural network route before I go down that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe winsorize them? It depends on what your intuition is about the data. Why do you not want to leave them as is? Do you think that a spike to 10'000 should be treated just like a 3 standard deviation spike? Then winsorization would help you. You may want to label data that was winsorized on the positive or negative end with an extra feature, given that you have enough data such that having extra features is not problematic.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to accomplish that is taking first differences of log-scaled data:

```
> log(1000000) - log(0.1)
[1] 16.1181
> log(1000000 / 0.1)
[1] 16.1181
```